# How to determine size of the drawable area of an OpenGL 3.3 window using GLFW

Tags: c++, glfw, opengl-3

I'm trying to create an game / application using GLFW and OpenGL 3.3. I'd like to be able to detect collision with the sides of the window, but it seems that the drawable area of the window differs from the size of the window set using `glfwCreateWindow()`.

So my question is, how do I get that drawable area, ie. the size of the window minus the border? I'd rather not have to use the WinAPI so as to make it more cross-platform, and `glfwGetWindowFrameSize()` is in GLFW 3.1, which isn't completed yet.

Edit: My question makes it seem like I need to use GLFW do accomplish this, which isn't true. I just wanted to note that I'm using GLFW as a window / input handler.

Comment: From looking at the documentation, `glfwGetFramebufferSize()` sounds like it might give the result you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`glfwGetFramebufferSize`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga0e2637a4161afb283f5300c7f94785c9).

`glfwGetVideoMode` returns the video mode of the specified monitor, not the size of your window. For fullscreen windows, they happen to be the same, but for other windows they are likely to be very different.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you do not *need* to know the size of the window, I'm assuming in pixels? If you want to do collision detection with the border of the window, you just need to detect the the NDC of your vertex, and once it reaches x or y = (-1, 1) then you would've had a collision. Nonetheless, if you want to get the size in pixels of your OpenGL context then use `glfwGetVideoMode()`.

Comment: Thank you, `glfwGetVideoMode()` is what I was looking for. I think going the NDC route may be a better option though. Currently the only time I use NDC is when I pass my vertices into the shader.

Comment: After some experimentation, it seems that glfwGetVideoMode is actually returning the incorrect numbers. As mentioned by @Colonel-Thirty-Two, it worked for full screen windows but nothing else.

Comment: GLFW can give you the size of the monitor (via `glfwGetVideoMode`), the size of the window (via `glfwGetWindowSize`), and the size of the framebuffer (`glfwGetFramebufferSize`). As you discovered, monitor size can equal framebuffer size when the window is full screen and a screen coordinate is equal to a pixel. But that's merely a coincidence. To be clear, `glfwGetVideoMode` is returning the (likely correct) numbers for *some other purpose*, not getting the window client area in pixels.